# Average length of time

Tags: prepositions, time

> a. How long does the average dating period last in your country?
>
> b. What is the average length of time for dating in your country?

Are the above sentences grammatically correct? Are they natural?

Answer (score 1):

Both of your options are grammatically correct, and mean pretty much the same thing, but the first one sounds a bit better to my ear and is how I would expect to see it phrased most of the time:

> How long does the average dating period last in your country?

This seems perfectly natural to me.

Answer (score 1):

Both are grammatically correct, but I wouldn't say either are the most natural way to ask that question. You don't often hear someone refer to "the dating period". Likewise, the word "dating" alone isn't specific enough - it could refer to a single date, or a prolonged period of dating.

I would prefer:

> What is the average length of time that couples date (for) in your country?

Even that is a little ambiguous - are you referring to the length of times couples date *until they break up*, or *until they get engaged / married*? It might pay to be specific.

Comment: I disagree that "dating" could refer to a single date in this case.  The use of "period" implies an extended duration, so "dating period" already implies a "prolonged period of dating".  As to naturalness, I think it depends a lot on context.  Yours might be more natural in casual speech, but "average dating period" I think would be quite natural in more formal or academic settings (and I don't really find it unnatural even in casual speech, personally).  Also including the "for" in your example is not only un-idiomatic (to my ear), but actually ungrammatical.  That form should not be used.